# How to build and link LuaJIT statically (VS 2013)

Tags: c++, linker, luajit, visual-studio-2013

Premise : I'd like my C++ application not to depend on whatever `Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable`, so I can ship my executable file that will work out of the box.

What I've done first : switching the runtime library to `Multithread (/MT)` from `DLL Multithread (/MD)` in order to avoid the need for `msvcr110.dll` (and shouldn't VS 2013 require the 120 version, as it's the compiler version ?). To do that I also had to recompile another library I'm using with the same runtime library, and that worked. I had my .exe which could be ran anywhere without problems (or I wasn't aware of, haha).

Then I added some functionalities that make use of LuaJIT. I've built LuaJIT by the `msvcbuild.bat` provided with the package and it worked like a charm, but now my executable requires the `msvcr110.dll` to run. I guess that's because LuaJIT was compiled with the /MD flag, but I'd like to know if there is a proper way to do what I want.

Comment: Do you need to load Lua/C modules at runtime..?

Comment: @NREZ This is the first time I use Lua, at the moment I only use it to execute some basic scripts. So I guess I don't need it (I have read the warning on the author's website).

Comment: Ok that is cool. Thing is that if you link it statically u will not face any dependency problems and if you still do, then you can use this cool tool named [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) which might help u sort it out. Always make sure that u are compiling other libs in `Release`. Though sometimes u might face a situation when you mandatorily need to include some .dll files and that time u can add them by making a setup file and including it in your installation, everyone does it. All the best in getting more info about it.

Comment: Changing /MD to /MT in msvcbuild.bat is fine and removes the dependency on the VS C++ runtime dll. What is the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't test this, but you most likely need to use the /MT flag on each piece of the compilation you do.  In this case, both your main program, and LuaJIT.  In that msvcbuild.bat file (https://github.com/luvit/luajit-2.0/blob/master/src/msvcbuild.bat) you can see that they are explicitly specifying /MD (line 17).  Methinks that is your problem.  Change it to /MT and see.

Comment: I have already tried this (but forgot to mention it ...) and thought it ran into errors when building my project. I tried it again, and by looking at the script closer I saw it accepts `static` as an argument. Combining the `/MT` flag and `static` got me exactly what I wanted. Thanks for making me investigate it, I'll let the bounty open for a little more information if we're lucky.

Comment: Don't forget to remove all occurences of /DLUA_BUILD_AS_DLL flag or else you will get missing DLL errors.

Answer (score 7):

You should run *msvcbuild.bat* with **static** command line parameter.

Comment: "msvcbuild.bat static". This is the right answer. Thanks.